# Can't connect with Remmina, I think my firewall is blocking it and I don't know what to allow in order to connect

Tags: firewall, remote-desktop

So, I've got my firewall set to deny all right now, except for an exception for my VPN, in order to make a kill switch in case it disconnects, problem is the firewall is blocking my Remmina connections and I can't figure out what to allow in order to get the connections going again.

Answer (score 1):

On my systems I connect through port 5900.

Assuming you use `ufw` as your firewall, you can open this port using the command  `sudo ufw allow 5900`.

Comment: +1 although personally I would recommend keeping 5900 closed and tunneling any VNC traffic over SSH

Comment: Good point. I use either VPN or SSH tunnel to connect to my internet-facing server from the outside world. 5900 is for connections within my LAN.

Comment: I've opened that port and am connecting locally but get the error message 
"Couldn't convert _computername_ to host address"

Comment: Are you giving *computername* to Remmina?  If so that needs to be associated with an IP address in your /etc/hosts file (at least that's what I did). I simpliifed my life by giving all my PCs fixed LAN IPs in my router and connect with Remmina using those IPs.